Rust analyser in neovim is underlining almost all words red in working code
I recently started to use nvim. I was doing a web API in rust using actix and I was faced with these red underlines in words that are neither misspelled words or errors, as the code runs just fine. I don't know what is causing this, either nvim or rust analyzer or even if its a feature.



It would be helpful to know more about your configuration? Are you using a preconfiguration like NvChad or LunarVim, what are the plugin that you are using? I suspect that you are using an LSP bridge but that it doesn't manage to be aware of the other compilation units (probably the current working directory is not set properly)

I think you should give How to debug my vimrc a read—you're better positioned to find out what makes the squigglies than we are.

TL;DR: rustup rust-src, reload nvim.
I had the same issue, and was frustrated for hours, to the point that figuring it out made me want to make a Stack Exchange account just to help the seemingly only other person in this situation.
You need to install the Rust standard library sources. Run rustup rust-src, or use your preferred package manager if that's how you have your Rust environment set up.
For future reference, if something like this happens to another language, try using the LSP function to jump to the definition of any standard lib's component. If it doesn't do anything, it can't find the standard lib, and usually that means no LSP support.

It's surprising to me that rust-analyzer requires the std source to be available to work properly (at least, I haven't had that problem), but I'm glad someone has found a solution!

Neovim's LSP specifically wants the source because, at least as far as I've experienced using the mason.nvim default rust-analyzer, it just checks the include sources. rust-analyzer as a standalone package doesn't care, but that setup specifically needs it. It's weird, and even weirder if you're using an nvim distribution. Worked On My LVim:tm:

Ah, somehow I missed that this answer was specific to Neovim, its LSP client, and possibly plugins. Good to know, thanks!

I didn't see your answer until now. And it worked. Thank you!
